# Linked system of differential inequalities $\frac{d}{dt} u_k(t)\leq C u_{k+1}(t)$ uniformly bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have an countably infinite family of smooth positive functions $\{u_k(t)\}$ which are all defined on some time interval $[0,T]$ which satisfy
$$
\frac{d}{dt}u_k(t)\leq Cu_{k+1}(t)
$$
for all $t\in [0,T]$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ where $C$ is a universal constant (assume $C=1$ if you like). Also assume that $u_k(0)$ are increasing up 1 as $k\to \infty$.

**My question is:** Is it true that the functions $u_k(t)\leq e^{Ct}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $t\in [0,T]$?

Of course if we instead had $\frac{d}{dt}u(t)\leq C u(t)$ with $u(0)\in [0,1]$, then $u(t)\leq e^{Ct}$ is always true. But this system is somewhat more unique.

I highly suspect this is true, and I also suspect there is a simple proof of this fact. But I have had no luck yet finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that $u_k(t) \le e^{Ct}$ for all $k$ and $t\in[0,T]$ is not true in general:

First note that if $\lambda > 0$, then for each $\mu \ge 2\lambda^2$ we have
$$
\lambda t \le \exp(\mu t^2/2) \quad (t \ge 0).
$$
For $t \in [0,1/\lambda]$ this inequality is trivially true and for $t \ge 1/\lambda$ we have
$$
\exp(\mu t^2/2) -\lambda t \ge 1+ \mu t^2/2 -\lambda t = 1+ t(\mu t/2-\lambda)\ge 1.
$$
Now, for fixed $T>0$  we construct functions $u_k:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$. Starting with any $\mu_1> 0$ and $u_1(t):=\exp(\mu_1 t^2/2)$ we can choose $\mu_2$ such that
$$
u_2(t):=\exp(\mu_2 t^2/2)
$$
satisfies
$$
u_1'(t) = \mu_1 t \exp(\mu_1 t^2/2) \le \exp(\mu_2 t^2/2) = u_2(t) \quad (t \in [0,T]),
$$
since we can arrange
$$
\mu_1t \le \exp((\mu_2-\mu_1)t^2/2) \quad (t \in [0,T])
$$
by choosing $\mu_2> \mu_1$ sufficiently big. In addition we can arrange $u_2(T) > \exp(T)$.

Then choose $\mu_3$ such that
$$
u_3(t):=\exp(\mu_3 t^2/2)
$$
satisfies
$$
u_2'(t) = \mu_2 t \exp(\mu_2 t^2/2) \le \exp(\mu_3 t^2/2) = u_3(t) \quad (t \in [0,T]),
$$
by choosing $\mu_3>\mu_2$ such that
$$
\mu_2t \le \exp((\mu_3-\mu_2)t^2/2) \quad (t \in [0,T])
$$
and $u_3(T) > \exp(T)$. By induction we obtain a sequence $(u_k)$ of positive functions on $[0,T]$ such that $u_k'(t) \le u_{k+1}(t)$ on $[0,T]$, $u_k(0)=1$ and $u_k(T)> \exp(T)$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.